# Is it standard to set is_authenticated to True in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm fairly new to Django and I use Django 4.2. I am making a website and I've been stuck in the logout logic. I'm confused as to whether I should have set the is_authenticated field to True by default in the models.py file.

I've googled a lot but I run don't understand how to really authenticate users in login and logout.

Can anyone help me understand the logic? Where do I use login decorators and how do I set the field is_authenticated to true during login and false during logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to set `is_authenticated` yourself as this read-only field is handled by the `AuthenticationMiddleware`.

Read more in the Django docs about:

- [is_authenticated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) attribute
- [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware)
- [authentication in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests)

This is how you will login a user in a custom view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login


def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
        ...
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
        ...
```

You can also use Django's handy classed based `LoginView`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView

And this is how you will logout a user in a custom view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
```

Or again with the handy [LogoutView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView).

You can check `is_authenticated` on `request.user` if needed.

With the [login decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), you can permit access to only logged in users. You can redirect unauthenticated users to `login_url` set in the decorator. Or if skipped, it will automatically redirect to `settings.LOGIN_URL`.

Comment: I used auth.login, is that still okay?

Comment: Please read the linked docs! As you can see in the example, you will log in the user with `login` after the user was authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

---

Inother to create a user authentication system, you need the user in built model or you create a new model and extend the user model to it.
Django has it's own authentication function that does the authentication by just taking in what the user posts the username and the password and does the database checking if it exists, if it returns true django has a same in built login funtion, that does the is_authenticated attribute to yes and after, whatever you want to do after login you put the logic,
there.
The logout also , django has same logout function you pass in the request and user , then turns the is_authenticated false to the user;

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        error_message = 'ERROR LOGIN. Please try again.'
         #TAKING USER BACK TO LOGIN PAGE
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'error_message': error_message})

return render(request, 'login.html')
```

def logout_view(request):
logout(request)
return redirect('home')